# Finding aggregate correlation of multiple columns against one column in r

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame with 11 columns out of which 9 are numeric. I am trying to find out the correlation of 8 columns together against the remaining column i.e., correlation of 8 variables with 1 variable which should generate one value of correlation instead of generating 9 different values in a matrix.

is it possible? or do I need to calculate the average correlation after calculating individual correlation?e.g., I am trying to find the correlation of X,Y,Z to A. Using the mentioned methods I get a matrix which gives me indivual score of association for X,Y,Z with A where as I need one score which takes into account all three X,Y & Z.

A simulated df is presented below for illustration purposes

```
          x            y           z   a
1   1.72480753  0.007053053  0.32435032  10
2   0.97227885 -0.844118498 -0.75534119  20
3  -0.53844294 -0.036178789  0.89396765  30
4   1.34695331  0.870119744  0.99400826  40
5   0.02336335  0.514481676  0.95894286  50
6  -0.15239307  0.386061290  0.73541287  60
7  -0.29878116  1.615012645 -0.04416341  70
8  -1.10907706 -1.581093487 -0.93293702  80
9   2.73021114 -0.130141775  1.85304372  90
10  0.22417487  1.170900385 -0.68312974 100
```

I can do correlation of each row and variable with a but what I want is correlation of x,y,z combined with a

```
corr.test(df[,1:3],df[,4])
```

I will appreciate any help towards this problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pearson Correlation is defined to be a number relating one sequence (or vector) of values to another (look it up). As far as I know there is no roughly equivalent definition for a group of vectors to another, but you could do something like take the average vector (of the 3 vectors) and correlate a to that.

To me at least that has a more immediate geometric meaning than taking the average of the 3 correlation values.

Comment: This makes more sense as the data has been standardised so taking the average will be a sensible choice. I was having problem averaging the correlations as the answer did not seem right. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. I think you probably don't need the code, it is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the correlation of each variable with `a`, you could do something like:

```
head(cor(df)[,"a"], -1)
#           x           y           z 
# -0.14301569  0.19188340 -0.06561505
```

You said you wanted to combine these values by averaging, so I suppose you could just take the mean of that:

```
mean(head(cor(df)[,"a"], -1))
# [1] -0.005582445
```